# I am trying to delete all the text from the word Description onwards in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

12 Piece Professional Grooming KitDescription:      12 Piece Professional Grooming Kit   Collection & delivery available. Postage costs start from £6, we will combine where we can to reduce postage costs.Condition: NewLocation: BCategory: Liquidations

so it would read as:

12 Piece Professional Grooming Kit

This needs to be able to work on multiple lines so the next entry would read as:

Foot Pump with Gauge

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(.+)Description")))
```

[image]

Comment: @gary-wild the answer updated take a look